# Fix Scrollview position when item is being added so it dosnt bump up/down

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have 2 recyclerviews being hosted inside a nested scrollview.

My problem is that, when I select items inside Recyclerview 2 they are being added into Recyclerview 1 but then the view is being pushed down and the user needs to scroll down to get to the initial position inside recyclerview 2. I added a `srolllistener` onto the parenting nested scrollview, and the y offset stays the same, so the whole behaviour makes somehow sense (since the whole view gets bigger by the item being added into recyclerview 1, and the offset stays the same, obviously this shift needs to happen), but its not what I want.

Is there a way to "fix" the view I have, so the YOffset changes automatically and there are no bumps? Funny thing is that when I remove items, and recyclerview 1 gets smalles there are not bumps when recyclerview 2 is being focused (I can remove an item if I tap again on it), and I want the same behaviour when adding new items.

[image]

Edit:

Here is the corresponding XML layout (AutofitRecyclerview is a regular recyclerview, where I according to the screen size, set the appropriate number of items inside a gridlayout of the recyclerview).
And when items from `recyclerview_items_category_products` are being selected and added into `recyclerview_items_selected` the whole views gets pushed up, and you alyways need to scroll a bit down to get to the position you were before the item was selected

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      tools:context=".ui.start.StartActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">


        <AutofitRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_items_selected"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/listitem" />

          

     
        <AutofitRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_items_category_products"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerview_items_selected"
            tools:listitem="@layout/listitem" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You want us to help you with your code without your code? how?

Comment: Not sure what code would be helpful. I was asking about a way to fix the position of the scrollview when one of the views inside it gets bigger. The best I could do is to post a layout xml that reflects my setup (actually I already posted the picture but I will post the xml too)